# How to Set up External yum repositories?

Tags: linux, yum

I am new to linux, I am trying to download package using yum, but looks like external repositories are not configured. how to setup yum to download packages from external repositories. I am using Redhat linux 5.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean RHEL-5, at which point you probably have the "yum-rhn-plugin" package installed ... which will give you access to the RHEL repositories as soon as you register with RHN (rhn_register).

You can also put files into /etc/yum.repos.d as "normal", Eg. for access to the EPEL repo.