# How to create Local Repositories in RHEL

Tags: repository, rhel-5

I need to create a local repository in RHEl 5.5 i386.

When I type some command in terminal it say that **RHEL is not subscribed with RHN** which is true because I took it from a friend.

So can someone tell me how to achieve this target?

Note: RHEL is installed on VirtualBox and the host system is Ubuntu.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to switch to CentOS?

Comment: How about these? http://superuser.com/questions/386254/adding-repo-to-yum http://superuser.com/questions/339568/how-to-set-up-external-yum-repositories